# Algebra. Equivalence of two expressions

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

While I was reading the solution to a question, I found this;

$a \cos^2{\theta}+2h \sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}+b \sin^2{\theta}$

$=a+2h\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}+(b-a)\sin^2{\theta}$

$=a+\sin{\theta}[2h\cos{\theta}+(b-a)\sin{\theta}]$

> $=a+\sin{\theta}\times\sqrt{4h^2+(b-a)^2} \times(\cos{\theta}\sin{\phi}+\sin{\theta} \cos{\phi})$

$a$ and $b$ are just constants and $\theta$ is inclination of some line with x axis (just for some context)

There is no mention of $\phi$ before or after this specific part of the solution or in the question. I don't seem to get how the last two expressions are equivalent, though first three steps are quite obvious. I assume there is some kind of substitution thingamajig going on but I haven't really seen anything like that being done. Or maybe it is a typological error. Any help in this matter will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It means $sinϕ=\frac{2h}{\sqrt{4h^2+(b-a)^2}}$, 
and $cosϕ=\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{4h^2+(b-a)^2}}$, 
and $ϕ∈[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Thanks; but I don't understand why would the author do that at all and why would he choose $\sqrt{4h^2+(b-a)^2}$ at all

Comment: The author do that probably because he wants to use the formula $cosθsinϕ+sinθcosϕ=sin(θ+ϕ)$. He chooses $\sqrt{4h^2+(b-a)^2}$ because $(2h)^2+(b-a)^2=4h^2+(b-a)^2$, and for any real number a, b that satisfy $a^2+b^2=1$, there must be an angle $ϕ$ that satisfy $cosϕ=a$ and $sinϕ=b$.